# sitecore query or tool to find broken items / templates (no longer exists)

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Looking for a quick and easy to query my entire sitecore database (master, web, or pub) and determine where the template for an item no longer exists.

I am trying to serialize my entire tree and I am finding that there are alot of items who's templates have been removed and would like to get a list of them without too much of a headache.

When viewing these items it says template: template no longer exists, here is the code that renders this

```
private static void RenderQuickInfoTemplate(HtmlTextWriter output, Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item)
    {
        Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item2;
        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(output, "output");
        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(item, "item");
        output.Write("<tr><td>");
        output.Write(Translate.Text("Template:"));
        output.Write("</td><td>");
        using (new SecurityDisabler())
        {
            item2 = item.Database.GetItem(item.TemplateID);
        }
        bool flag = (item2 != null) && (CommandManager.QueryState("shell:edittemplate", item) == CommandState.Enabled);
        if (flag)
        {
            output.Write("<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"javascript:scForm.postRequest('','','','shell:edittemplate');return false\">");
        }
        if (item2 != null)
        {
            output.Write(item2.Paths.Path);
        }
        else
        {
            output.Write(Translate.Text("[template no longer exists]"));
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i think items which base on deleted templates don't inherit from (standard) base template anymore. in quickinfo you should see that their template-ID is something like {000-0000-0000...}

you could try find all the items based on this id.

Comment: the thing about it is that the template id is a valid guid. making me thinking think that the value is stored as a string without any referential integrity.

Comment: This assumption is wrong (at least with sitecore 7.5): The template ID is stored with the item, so it doesn't necessarily get reset when the template is deleted. The OP and me had the issue with a template ID not corresponding to a template. It should get updated when deleting the template based on the link db.

Answer (score 0):

Two options that come to mind:

1. Check the Broken Links report
2. You can right-click on the left 'rail' in the content editor and choose "Broken Links" to show all items that have broken links.

Comment: As an additional note, if you are finding the Broken Links report is not working, make sure you rebuild the Link index in the administration console.

Comment: while this works for actual links, not sure it works for the template problem as I tried this approach before posting

Answer (score 0):

Using the popular powershell module, try

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "master:\sitecore" -Recurse | ForEach-Object {if (!$_.Template){        write-host $_.ItemPath    }}
```

For me that returns a whole lot of items that I can't open in the content editor.

In case it's just a few items and you want to do everything manually, you can use the dbbrowser:

```
<yoursiteurl>/sitecore/admin/dbbrowser.aspx.
```

In case you want to delete these items by script (when there are too many)

```
$myItemArray = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
Get-ChildItem -Path "master:\sitecore\content" -Recurse | ForEach-Object {if (!$_.Template){
$myItemArray.Add($_)
}}
#Show list of Items with invalid template
$myItemArray | Format-Table -Auto -Property Templateid, ItemPath
#Show count of affected items
$myItemArray.Count
$myItemArray #| Remove-Item -recurse
```

To actually delete the items, remove the '#' in the final line at your own risk. The script takes quite some time to run, and you might need to change the path in case you have broken items outside of content.